# RegEx digit (only 4 digit) and ,

Tags: javascript, regex

I need validate digits and ', ' but with this condicions:

1. Only groups of 4 digits separated with ','
2. no use | (pipe) in the regex.
3. no white space.
4. No limit of groups (2345,2345,....n)

Examples:

```
1234 //correct
1234, //correct
8764,8745 //correct
8974,9874,4567,3456, //correct
8974,9874,4567,3456,2345,3456,3456 //correct


23 //incorrect
2344,23445657,8753 //incorrect
8475,2344565788,8753 //incorrect
8475,34 //incorrect
8475,34,5676,8890 //incorrect
```

My regex is:

```
^([\d]{4},?)+$ // but acept:  2344,23445657,8753 ->incorrect
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow for a trailing comma? If you don't , a very common pattern could be `^\d{4}(?:,\d{4})*$`. Include an optional comma at the end if you must.

Comment: Also, why the artificial restrictions? That said, remember to use https://regex101.com/ to build and test your pattern.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think your answer was good. You only had to add `,?` at the end.

Comment: that's true; undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

`([\d]{4},?)+` says "4 numbers, and then an *optional* comma, one or more times, so it will happily accept 12345678 because that's four numbers, no comma (which *matches* the `,?`) and then four numbers. What you want is "always first four numbers" because that's the minimal pattern it needs to match, followed by zero or more groups that *have* to start with a comma, and finally, an isolated optional comma.

`^\d{4}(,\d{4})*,?$`

And to verify, we use regex101: https://regex101.com/r/o5MhS9/1

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is

```
^(\d{4},)*(\d{4})?$
```

The empty string is not considered by the test cases so it's unclear if it's correct or not.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine you want to use this for validation purposes when submitting something.  Regex is a nice tool, but it could give you some undesired behaviors like give you multiple positives.

I wonder if it would be better to create something that breaks down your string and evaluates each piece, like:

```js
let valid1 = "1234,1234,1234";
let valid2 = "1234,1234,1234,4565";
let invalid1 = "1234,1234,12341";
let invalid2 = "1234,12312344,1231";

function validateFourDigitsCommaSeparated(stringToValidate)
{
    let sequences = stringToValidate.split(',');
    let hasInvalidSequence = false;
    let hasValidSequence = false;
    let fourDigitExactlyRegex = /^\d{4}$/;
        
    sequences.forEach(function(sequence) 
      {
        if(sequence.match(fourDigitExactlyRegex))
        {
          hasValidSequence = true;
        }
        else {
          hasInvalidSequence = true;
        }
      }
    );
    
    return hasValidSequence && hasInvalidSequence === false;
}

console.log('valid1', valid1, validateFourDigitsCommaSeparated(valid1));
console.log('valid2', valid2, validateFourDigitsCommaSeparated(valid1));
console.log('invalid1', invalid1, validateFourDigitsCommaSeparated(invalid1));
console.log('invalid2', invalid2, validateFourDigitsCommaSeparated(invalid2));
```

Comment: Hola, en este caso necesito usar regex ya que utilizo un framework y no quiero entrar a modificar código del framework... gracias de todas formas